# Does a query against a nested field in BigQuery count only the size of the subfield as the "Processed Data Amount" in on-demand pricing?

Tags: google-bigquery

The other possibility is that the "Processed Data Amount" has the size of the top, enclosing STRUCT/RECORD type even though only one subfield of the STRUCT/RECORD column is selected.

The online [doc](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#data) has that "0 bytes + the size of the contained fields", which is not explicit to me. Can someone help to clarify? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Think of a record as a storage mechanism.  When you query against it (like you would a regular table), you are still only charged for the columns you use (select, filter, join, etc).

Check out the following query estimates for these similar queries.

```
-- This query would process 5.4GB
select 
  *  -- everything
from `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_*`

-- This query would process 33.7MB
select 
  visitorId,   -- integer
  totals       -- record
from `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_*`

-- This query would process 6.9MB
select 
  visitorId,   -- integer
  totals.hits  -- specific column from record
from `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_*`
```

Comment: That was actually what I believed. Thanks for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

[On-demand pricing](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#on_demand_pricing) is based on the number of bytes processed by a query, in the Struct/Record data type you are charged according to the columns you select within the Record.

The expression  “0 bytes + the size of the contained fields” means that the size will depend on the columns data types within the record.

Moreover, you can estimate costs before running your query using the [query validator](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/best-practices-costs#using_the_query_validator)